# Ionic 4: How to update or refresh a ion-select from script?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I created an app with a register form in ionic 4 and angular.    I want to do the following:

I have two ion-selects,  one is for a countries list and that another is for  phone codes list.  The behavior i am looking for is:  when a country is selected in the ion-select for countries, the corresponding telephone code must be selected automatically in the phone code ion-select.

This is my code:

ion-select for countries

```
  <ion-select  id="paisselect" formControlName="pais" (ionChange)="changeselect($event)" interface="popover">

    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{c.cod}}">{{c.name}}</ion-select-option>

 </ion-select>
```

ion-select for phone code

```
    <ion-select formControlName="phonecode" placeholder="Cod." interface="popover">

    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of codetele" value="{{c.code}}" selected="{{codigoselected == c.code}}">{{c.code}}</ion-select-option>

</ion-select>
```

Here is the function i am using to update the phone code ion-select

```
changeselect($event){
    console.log($event.target.value) ;
    let item1 = this.countries.find(i => i.cod === $event.target.value);
    console.log(item1) ;
    this.codigoselected = item1.code;
    console.log(this.codigoselected) ;
}
```

I am using the variable "codigoselected" to determine which country is selected.  for this, in the ion-select-option  i am using a condition to change the  selected status of the option like this:

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of codetele" value="{{c.code}}" selected="{{codigoselected == c.code}}">{{c.code}}</ion-select-option>
```

The current behavior is like this:

I selected a country:

[image]

But the ion-select for phone codes seems not to be updated

[image]

But when I click on the field, the specific code is selected

[image]

I need to do clic under option is selected in order to field be refreshed:

[image]

So, how can I make the field for phone codes update automatically in the interface without the user clicking?

Comment: Why don't you update the form control value? Instead of `this.codigoselected = item1.code` perhaps something like `this.yourFormGroup.value.phonecode = item1.code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, pass the phone code select element to your `changeselect(event, phoneCodeSelect)` function.

```
<ion-select  id="paisselect" formControlName="pais" (ionChange)="changeselect($event, phoneCodeSelect)" interface="popover">

    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{c.cod}}">{{c.name}}</ion-select-option>

 </ion-select>
```

Add `#phoneCodeSelect` to your phone code select element.

```
<ion-select #phoneCodeSelect formControlName="phonecode" placeholder="Cod." interface="popover">

    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of codetele" value="{{c.code}}" selected="{{codigoselected == c.code}}">{{c.code}}</ion-select-option>

</ion-select>
```

Then in your function change the value of the select element manually, while also updating the phoneCode form control value.

```
changeselect($event, phoneCodeSelect){
    console.log($event.target.value) ;
    let item1 = this.countries.find(i => i.cod === $event.target.value);
    console.log(item1) ;
    this.yourFormGroup.value.phonecode = item1.code; // change yourFormGroup to what your variable's name is 
    phoneCodeSelect.value = item1.code;
}
```